Group a list by a field, which in turn is a list
I have a class for movies:
class Movie:
    def __init__(self,
                 title: str,
                 director: str,
                 actors: list[str]):
        self.title = title
        self.director = director
        self.actors: list[str] = actors

And a list with 3 example movies:
movies = [Movie('Barton Fink', 'Joel Coen', ['John Turturro', 'John Goodman', 'Judy Davis']),
          Movie('The Big Lebowski', 'Joel Coen', ['Jeff Bridges', 'John Goodman', 'Steve Buscemi', 'John Turturro']),
          Movie('The Big Easy', 'Jim McBride', ['Dennis Quaid', 'Ellen Barkin', 'John Goodman']),
         ]

I use Pandas to get the number of occurrences of all actors:
John Goodman: 3
John Turturro: 2
Judy Davis: 1
...

For the directors it works this way:
df = DataFrame([vars(m) for m in movies])
grouped = df.groupby(['director']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
print(df)

But for the actors not:
df = DataFrame([vars(m) for m in movies])
grouped = df.groupby(['actors']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
print(df)

This doesn't work, because unlike user-defined classes (by default) or tuples, lists aren't hashable:

Error: (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'"), <traceback object at 0x00000274C91E4340>)

How can I group by the list of actors?

As I understood from the error, to group the data you need to have a hashable (immutable) data type. In python lists are mutable. So converting the actor list into a tuple or a set would solve the grouping problem but it might not solve what you want to achieve.

@E.Dem No, it won't. The question wasn't about grouping by list. And I wonder why @mozway closed the post as a duplicate of the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' question because OP is not about this error.

@Vitalizzare I think it was closed as a duplicate because of the error message appearing in the question; however, I agree with you that that misses the point.  I've edited further to emphasize that, and it's reopened now.

You don't need pandas for this.  You can use collections.Counter.
from collections import Counter

Counter(actor for movie in movies for actor in movie.actors)


What we can see here is an example of XY problem. I'm sure the initial purpose wasn't to group by lists, but rather to count the number of movies for each actor, since the expected output looks as follows:
John Goodman: 3
John Turturro: 2
Judy Davis: 1
...

In Pandas, we can do this with value_counts and explode:
director_occurrences = df['director'].value_counts()
actor_occurences = df['actors'].explode().value_counts()

print(director_occurrences, '', actor_occurences, sep='\n')

director
Joel Coen      2
Jim McBride    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

actors
John Goodman     3
John Turturro    2
Judy Davis       1
Jeff Bridges     1
Steve Buscemi    1
Dennis Quaid     1
Ellen Barkin     1
Name: count, dtype: int64

